# PowerPoint Add-In add html iFrame to slide

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins, powerpoint-web-addins

I want to create an Add-In where I can set an URL via textbox and by clicking the apply button the iframe gets added to a new slide at the end of the presentation. I could add an iFrame with content app but unfortunatelly it is not working with saving the powerpoint.

I know how to add the slide and also simple text boxes or shapes on it but how can I add an iFrame?

Here's the code snippet where I would like to add an iframe to the slide. I've tried it with shapes without success and I have no idea how to continue...

```
async function addIFrameToSlide(slideIndex) {        
        const iframe = getIFrame();

        await PowerPoint.run(async function(context) {
            const shapes = context.presentation.slides.getItemAt(slideIndex).shapes;
            
            
            await context.sync();
        });       


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Office JavaScript API doesn't provide anything for embedding iframes out of the box. But you may consider developing [Content Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/content-add-ins) instead.

`Content add-ins` are surfaces that can be embedded directly into Excel or PowerPoint documents. Content add-ins give users access to interface controls that run code to modify documents or display data from a data source. Use content add-ins when you want to embed functionality directly into the document.

Note, you can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.

Comment: Okay I've tried the content app too and its not possible to save the iFrame.
I've got a textbox where I can provide the url for the iFrame and by clicking the button it gets displayed but when I reload the powerpoint it reloads the content app and I can see the textbox again.

var iFrame = getIFrame();

document.body.innerHTML = ''; // Set body to empty
document.body.appendChild(iFrame); // add iframe to document body

How can I save it?